# If the limit of the integrals is zero then the limit of the functions is zero a.e.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions such that $f_n: X \to ([0,\infty])$ is measurable for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_1 \geq f_2 \geq \dots$.

I am asked to show that if $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\int\limits_{X}f_n d\mu = 0$ then $f_n$ converges to the function zero almost everywhere.

I also wonder if the other direction holds.

I am having trouble because I can't apply any of the convergence theorems that we've learned.

Answer (score 2):

How about Fatou:

$$\int_X \liminf f_n \le \liminf \int_x f_n = 0.$$

Now use that the $f_n$ are decreasing.

The other direction is not true. Take $f_n =\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2}\chi_{[n,\infty]}$.

Comment: Nice comment, the type of function given as a counterexample is very useful for these types of questions of convergence.

Comment: I don't understand how you are supposed to use that the $f_n$ are decreasing. I know that if the sequence is decreasing then $\int\limits_X \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n d\mu = \int\limits_X \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n d\mu = 0$ but does that imply that $f_n$ converges to zero a.e.?

Comment: The decreasing property lets you upgrade the liminf to a limit. Now the limit is some nonnegative measurable function whose integral is zero.